Power dynamics between Krogstad and Nora in A Doll's House
I have been studying the text A Doll's House, and was wondering how to analyse the power dynamics between Krogstad and Nora in the play.
Would most say that Krogstad in act 1, despite having the blackmail against Nora, actually is subservient to Nora for the fact that he had to go to a woman to plea to help to keep his job (considered shameful in the era)? But how would this be in alignment with the way he seems to be so dominant and brash in his dialogue? Also, how do we analyse the power dynamics between Nora and Krogstad with respect to how Nora seemed to be like "Oh, I have influence" but when asked for a favour suddenly said she didn't?
